# What holds the small rubber feet on the bottom of the Magic Keyboard II

Tags: keyboard

Two of the small rubbery feet on the bottom of my Magic Keyboard II have fallen off. I managed to save one of them, the other is gone.

Does anyone know what is supposed to hold these into the keyboard? It does not appear to be an adhesive, but it doesn't seem to be a friction fit either?

Any ideas on how to reconnect these?

**UPDATE:** image added. The rubbery bit has an extension that fits into the slot you can see on the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: I do not know what **Apple** uses, however, a piece of double-sided tape, or good old fashioned rubber cement will do the job. If using the latter, test with a drop from a toothpick where the foot goes to make sure there is not an adverse reaction if the surface is plastic.

Comment: Its not rubber on the bottom though. It's some sort of very slippery plastic, almost like telflon. Nothing sticks to it.

Comment: Could you add a picture of one of the feet you salvaged? I don't have a new Magic Keyboard II, but I have the original (battery) Magic Trackpad and have re-inserted feet that fell off before. If the feet are similar to the original Magic Trackpad, I could help you get them back on.

Comment: I have the same problem but for the Magic Keyboard 1.  I did use the double-side tape to stick it back but after a while the tape glue leaks out and the pad becomes a mess that must be cleaned and the whole operation repeated.  I wish there was a cleaner way to fix those.